# What's the best word to simulate an adjectival form of "camaraderie"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, derivational-morphology

I thought that *'camaraderous'* was a word, but it turns out it isn't. As a matter of fact, I can't seem to find anything resembling an adjectival form for 'camaraderie'. So could someone suggest a fitting substitute? i.e. an adjective meaning "possessing the characteristics of camaraderie?"

I was thinking of using it like:

> After their hard-won victory, John and Trent slung their arms around
> each other's shoulders in a *camaraderous* embrace.

Comment: It would be [*comradely*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comradely).

Comment: @Mick - comment boxes are not supposed to be used to post  answers, why do you keep posting potentially  good answers here?

Comment: Darn. I thought I'd tried all the typical permutations of comrade, but I guess I must've skipped that one. Great answer! Thanks! :-D

Comment: I would, if such terse answers were accepted by the community, but they're not. Others do the same, even mods. I don't have time to copy, paste and format dictionary definitions. Perhaps if there is a quick way of doing it...

Comment: @Mick - copying and pasting would just take the time you have spent answering my question. What's the problem with it. If you have the answer, post it, don't post a comment. (And the same is valid for ELL)

Comment: @JOSH OK. Done, but I don't particularly like it. If there was some automatic way of producing nicely formatted text, it would be a no-brainer. I would like to know how other users manage it.

Comment: @Mick - on top of the answer box there are a number of functions that enables you to format an answer the way you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be [***comradely***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comradely):

(graded adjective & adjective [usu ADJ n])

> - If you do something in a comradely way, you are being pleasant and friendly to other people. [formal]
> - *They worked in comradely silence.*

Collins Dictionary

Comment: @JOSH - Thank you for formatting the answer.  Mick, I had a rough two weeks or so when I was retraining myself to write formatted, referenced answers, and I can say that with practice it does get easier and ingrained as a habit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you use adjectival ***comradely*** the allusion is to [***comradeliness***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/comradeliness), which loses the precise nuance of ***camaraderie*** (which we usually *want* - since that's why we *use* the word).

So I'd go with [the handful of writers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22camaradic%22) who've used

***camaradic***

The meaning should always be obvious in context, even though I doubt you'd find an actual definition in any dictionary.

In short, the "consistent" pairings are *comradeliness -> comradely, camaraderie -> camaradic*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and straightforward option would be ***friendly***.

> After their hard-won victory, John and Trent slung their arms around
>   each other's shoulders in a ***friendly*** embrace.

M-W:

> **[friendly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friendly)**
>   *adjective*   [friendlier; friendliest]
>
> **1** :  of, relating to, or befitting a friend: as
>   **a** :  showing kindly interest and goodwill
>   **b** :  not hostile : *a friendly merger offer*; also :  involving or coming from actions of one's own forces : *friendly fire*
>   **c** :  cheerful, comforting : *the friendly glow of the fire*
>
> His friendly smile was reassuring.
>   They maintained a friendly
>   correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge for you whether one of the other answers serves your purpose.  But here is another option for you to consider:

> After their hard-won victory, John and Trent slung their arms around each other's shoulders **in camaraderie**.

Sorry I don't have a new word to offer.  But *camaraderie* is a great word, and it fits fine in your sentence with a small adjustment.  And the *embrace* you had was superfluous anyway.

I wasn't sure how to reference this, so I googled the exact phrase "in camaraderie".  I didn't find it in a dictionary, but I did find it in a [blog post](http://figure%20skaters%20executing%20incredible%20maneuvers,%20in%20camaraderie,%20I%20guess,%20with%20their%20own%20bodies).  So I guess it's not just me.  Here's the sentence fragment:

> ... figure skaters executing incredible maneuvers, **in camaraderie**, I guess, with their own bodies....